# If/Else nightmare. jQuery Optimization tips?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, optimization

I have the following (example) jQuery code within a function that as you can see contains some awful if/else statements with a lot of repetition of sorts. Is there a better (more performance, DRY, readable) way of going about all these if/else statements?

I'm not trying to just concatenate the different options either, the result of each if will be very different in each case.

```
var qux = "";

if (foo == 'a') {
    if (bar == 'x') {
        if (baz == 'm') {
            qux = $('#div').html('result 1');
        } else if (baz == 'n') {
            qux = $('#div').html('result 2');
        }
    } else if (bar == 'y') {
        if (baz == 'm') {
            qux = $('#div').html('result 3');
        } else if (baz == 'n') {
            qux = $('#div').html('result 4');
        }
    } else if (bar == 'z') {
        if (baz == 'm') {
            qux = $('#div').html('result 5');
        } else if (baz == 'n') {
            qux = $('#div').html('result 6');
        }
    }
} else if (foo == 'b') {
    if (bar == 'x') {
        if (baz == 'm') {
            qux = $('#div').html('result 7');
        } else if (baz == 'n') {
            qux = $('#div').html('result 8');
        }
    } else if (bar == 'y') {
        if (baz == 'm') {
            qux = $('#div').html('result 9');
        } else if (baz == 'n') {
            qux = $('#div').html('result 10');
        }
    } else if (bar == 'z') {
        if (baz == 'm') {
            qux = $('#div').html('result 11');
        } else if (baz == 'n') {
            qux = $('#div').html('result 12');
        }
    }
} else if (foo == 'c') {
    if (bar == 'x') {
        if (baz == 'm') {
            qux = $('#div').html('result 13');
        } else if (baz == 'n') {
            qux = $('#div').html('result 14');
        }
    } else if (bar == 'y') {
        if (baz == 'm') {
            qux = $('#div').html('result 15');
        } else if (baz == 'n') {
            qux = $('#div').html('result 16');
        }
    } else if (bar == 'z') {
        if (baz == 'm') {
            qux = $('#div').html('result 17');
        } else if (baz == 'n') {
            qux = $('#div').html('result 18');
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Changed code for clarification.

Comment: I think the real nightmare is using = instead of ==. Also, why is this needed in the first place? Think about what you're trying to do. Why not just add `foo`, `bar` and `baz`?

Comment: Concatenate `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` and use it as a key into a lookup table... though it looks like you'd be fine with just concatenating them (unless that was just for the example).

Comment: You can concatenate foo, bar and baz into an array then mapping through   it. using map function or forEach.

Comment: Here's a quick way with switch statements: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljmukr5m/

Comment: Sorry all, the combining for qux was just an example, I'm not trying to concatenate, each result will be completely different.. editing question to clarify..

Comment: `switch(foo + bar + baz) { case "axm": ... break; case "bxm": ... break; case "cxm": ... break; }` ...and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different options I'd consider to neaten up your code are as follows:

1. A small change: given that every single case does `$("#div").html('result xx')`, just set:

   ```
   if (foo == 'a') {
       if (bar == 'x') {
           if (baz == 'm') {
               qux = 'result 1';
           } else if (baz == 'n') {
               qux = 'result 2';
           }
   // etc.
   ```

   and then after the if/else structure say:

   ```
   if (qux != "") qux = $("#div").html(qux)
   ```

   At least that way you're not having to repeat the `$("#div").html()` part everywhere. It would still be a giant, ugly `if/else` structure, but this option might make sense if your real-world code has more complicated combinations of test conditions that can't easily be combined.
2. Given that the `if/else` example you show is based on various combinations of the same three variables' values, you can replace the structure with a lookup table, perhaps something like the following:

   ```
   var lookupTable = {
     'a:x:m' : 'result 1',
     'a:x:n' : 'result 2',
     'a:y:m' : 'result 3',
     'a:y:n' : 'result 4',
     //...
     'b:x:m' : 'result 7',
     'b:x:n' : 'result 8',
     // ...
     'c:x:m' : 'result 13',
     'c:x:n' : 'result 14',
     // ...
     'c:z:n' : 'result 18'
   };

   var qux = lookupTable[foo + ':' + bar + ':' + baz];
   if (qux) {  // qux will be undefined if foo/bar/baz combination not in table
     $("#div").html(qux);
   }
   ```

Either way you might consider encapsulating the calculation in a function, so that it doesn't clutter up the code around it, leaving a call something like:

```
// other code
var result = calculate(foo, bar, baz);
if (result) $("#div").html(result);
// more other code
```

(Note: I don't understand why you would initialise `qux` as an empty string and then in the if/else structure set it to the return value from `.html('some result')`, because that return value would be a jQuery element which doesn't seem like a sensible alternative to a string, but anyway...do or don't include code for that as required.)